# Make a js array with the value of an input box separated by spaces

Tags: javascript, arrays, input

I am trying to make an user input with a text box and put them into an array.  Basically if a user inputs a string like 
10 23 4566 234 10
I would like the numbers to be put into an array like [10, 23, 4566, 234, 10].  Is this possible?  I'm only working with numbers and the string might get long.

Comment: What have you got so far? This can be achieved by using var str=document.getElementById("-").value and then splitting it into an array. var res =str.split(" ");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this:

```
let numbers = "10 23 4566 234 10".split(' ').map(Number)
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll use this because it's all on one line.  Is there any difference if I have numbers be a variable?

Comment: No there isn't, but i find this way better :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use `String.prototype.split` like so:

```
var str = "1 2 4 9 18 7";
var array = str.split(" ");
```

If you need them to be numbers:

```
var numArray = array.map(Number);
```

Comment: It works! thanks! but, Nick's answer is all on one line, so I'll use that.  Great answer though!